The "description" property causes OneDrive Graph API calls to fail when using personal accounts created before 2019/11
I'm following Upload large files with an upload session to call OneDrive Graph API.
Account "A" was created before 2019/11, and account "B" was created recently.
Account "A" and "B" can use OneDrive on the web and they are both personal accounts.
Request 1
{
  "item": {
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename",
    "description": "",
    "fileSystemInfo": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.fileSystemInfo"},
    "name": "ttttt.jpg"
  }
}

If using account "A", the response is as follows:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "Invalid request",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2024-09-30T12:52:59",
      "request-id": "9c768b04-0dfd-41d1-a3f0-69c223536fa6",
      "client-request-id": "9c768b04-0dfd-41d1-a3f0-69c223536fa6"
    }
  }
}

If using account "B", the response is as follows:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.uploadSession",
  "expirationDateTime": "2024-10-05T13:17:50.988Z",
  "nextExpectedRanges": ["0-"],
  "uploadUrl": "https://api.onedrive.com/rup/1fe3b5cce115f141/eyJSZXNvdXJjZUlEIjoiMUZFM0......"
}

Now just remove description from the request.
Request 2
{
  "item": {
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename",
    "fileSystemInfo": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.fileSystemInfo"},
    "name": "ttttt.jpg"
  }
}

If using account "A", the response is as follows:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.uploadSession",
  "expirationDateTime": "2024-10-05T13:17:50.988Z",
  "nextExpectedRanges": ["0-"],
  "uploadUrl": "https://api.onedrive.com/rup/1fe3b5cce115f141/eyJSZXNvdXJjZUlEIjoiMUZFM0......"
}

If using account "B", the response is as follows:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.uploadSession",
  "expirationDateTime": "2024-10-05T13:17:50.988Z",
  "nextExpectedRanges": ["0-"],
  "uploadUrl": "https://api.onedrive.com/rup/1fe3b5cce115f141/eyJSZXNvdXJjZUlEIjoiMUZFM0......"
}

Why does the description in the request cause the request to fail for account "A" but work for account "B"?
The API call
{
  "item": {
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename",
    "description": "",
    "fileSystemInfo": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.fileSystemInfo"},
    "name": "ttttt.jpg"
  }
}

Result

Personal account "A" (created before 2019/11) fails.
Personal account "B" (created recently) succeeds.
Work account "C" fails.

Exception
Personal account "A" should succeed, but it fails.
